# Edit related object using ModelFormSet

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I was using a model formset to generate a table of forms for a list of objects.

Forms:

```
class UserTypeModelForm(ModelForm):
    account_type = ChoiceField(label='User type',
                               choices=ACCOUNT_OPTIONS, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('account_type',)


UserTypeModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(get_user_model(),
                                            form=UserTypeModelForm, 
                                            extra=0)
```

View:

```
formset = UserTypeModelFormSet(queryset=users, prefix='formset')
```

Now my client wants to be able to modify a related field: user.employee_profile.visible.

I tryed to add a field to the form, and then passing "initial" and "queryset" to the formset, but It looks like it just takes one.

How would you guys do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with model formsets, the initial values only apply to extra forms, those that aren’t bound to an existing object instance.
>   [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values)

The `queryset` provides the selected/entered values for the bound fields, the `initial` for the extra fields (in your case 0).

But you can override the initial value in e.g. your views when you created a field called `employee` in this case:

```
for form in forms:
    # Don't override a selected value.
    if not form.fields['employee'].initial:
        form.fields['employee'].initial = my_init
```